# How to nest views in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I'm pretty new to Rails, but I've gotten stuck on a seemingly simple problem, where I'm trying to create nested layouts, with each controller having their own layout rendered within the application layout. E.g. the application-layout renders a top menu, the controller layout renders a (controller specific) submenu, and the action renders the actual content view.

The point of this exercise is to be able to (from the controller) optionally render the action specific view without any of the two layouts, for instance when using PJAX.

So basically:

```
<application-layout>
  <controller-layout>
    <action-view>
  </controller-layout>    
</application-layout>
```

My guess so far is that I could use something in the likes of:

```
<% content_for :submenu, render(:partial => 'users/submenu') %>
```

But I'm not sure if this is a good approach? Is there an automatic way of doing this? Can I load a layout from within another layout?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, but this is right in the Rails Guides. Downvoting.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts%5Fand%5Frendering.html#using-nested-layouts

Comment: Wow, sorry about that. I read that section twice but still managed to misunderstand. Thank you for your quick reply.